# Where within Let, Haskell Scoping,

Tags: haskell, scope, where-clause, let

I want to have access to a let-binding within a following where-clause.

Why does this Code fail?
And even more important: How do I get it to work?

```
test bar = let baz = bar - 1 in
 foo where
  foo = baz`
```

it says:
Not in scope: `baz'
    Perhaps you meant`bar'

Comment: Did you really mean to write `baz'` or was it `baz` that you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of a *where* as another way to write a *let* around the right hand sides that belong to a single match.

In your case, it is quite easy, as there is only a single right hand side. Hence, you wrote:

```
test bar = let foo = baz in let baz = bar-1 in foo
```

This is not going to work. I recommend to stick with either *where* or *let*, most idiomatic would be:

```
test bar = foo
    where
       foo = baz
       baz = bar -1
```

Apart from that, when you only define `baz` then `baz'` will never be in scope.

Answer (score 0):

`where` clauses can only access the parameters of the enclosing function and any higher-level bindings. You can pass `baz` as a parameter to `foo`:

```
test bar = let baz = bar - 1 in (foo baz)
  where foo x = x
```